# Preparing segue in Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I have collection view implemented but have an error for the segue. I am trying to hand the image to another view controller using a segue.  This is the code for it.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showImage", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "showImage"
    {
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! NewViewController
        vc.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]!
        vc.title = self.appleProducts[indexPath.row]
    }
}

 }
```

However I am having an error at `collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems`saying that Could not find member indexPathsForSelectedItems. Why is this happening and how should it be changed. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have mode some changes to your code

**Add following changes in your code**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showImage", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "showImage"
    {
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath           
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! NewViewController
        vc.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]!
        vc.title = self.appleProducts[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I now get two more errors stating, "UICollectionViewCell?"is not convertible to UICollection View. and also an error saying AnyObject? is not convertible to UICollectionViewCell did you mean to use as! to force downcast?

Comment: On which line you are getting this => "UICollectionViewCell?"is not convertible to UICollection View. For, AnyObject? is not convertible to UICollectionViewCell. Try to force downcast.

Comment: `let cell = sender as UICollectionViewCell` This code.

Comment: I have made some changes in answer, try this updated code